# How to make directive rendering faster inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some many items to load.

So I have give in `ng-repeat`. Under that, I am using one directive. So directive should load on every item.

Here, It is taking time to load basic view after complete all the items in `ng-repeat`.

So, I need to view(render) single by single item. Actually, view  shouldn't wait for complete `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="site in siteList>
<stock-chart graph-site="site" graph-params="graphParams" ></stock-chart>
</div>
```

Here, I have watchers for `graphParams` and `graphSite`.

How can we write a code for this?

Comment: You want to show that in progressive manner. right?

Comment: yeah. It is taking more time to render single item

Comment: You can play around with some CSS transition & animations with opacity and try using that class on these repetitive `div's`, I know won't make any impact on the performance, but will improve the UI impact.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to render faster, but you can do several tricks to make UI more responsive:

- Use custom filter to determine when user is in a bottom of the view
  and render more values from original array.
- Use "track by" expression to avoid additional rendering.

Here is a live example for you:

https://plnkr.co/edit/onSjuQL8aB3iXGBamP28?p=preview

Track by:

```
<div ng-repeat="site in siteList | scrollFilter:this:100 track by site.id">
```

Filter:

```
app.filter('scrollFilter', function() {
  var bottomScrolledCount = 1,
      scope = null;
  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      if (scope) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          bottomScrolledCount++;
        })
      }
    }
  };
  return function(values, fscope, length) {
    scope = fscope;
    var filterResult = [];
    for (i = 0, len = Math.min(values.length, length * bottomScrolledCount); i < len; i++) {
      filterResult.push(values[i]);
    }
    console.log(filterResult.length);
    return filterResult
  }
})
```

The core idea is to pass rendering items limit to filter and check if page is scrolled to the bottom using window.onscroll event. Because of track by expression it won't take more time to render old items. Only new ones will be added to view.

Also, you need to pass scope to your filter in order to use $apply method.